# problem on existence of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq1/\lvert z\rvert$ for all $\lvert z\rvert\geq5$?

My Attempt:

As $\lvert z\rvert\to\infty, \lvert f(z)\rvert\to0$.

So, $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=\infty$, so $f$ must be identically $1$, but the answer says that there does not exist any such entire function.

What is wrong in the above?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Liouville's theorem?

Comment: If $f$ is identically $1$, then $|f(z)|>1/|z|$ for $|z|\ge5$.

Comment: @AbhishekShrivastava yes, but it cannot be identically one because then it would not satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there exists an entire function $f$with $f(0) = 1$ and $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|} \leq \frac{1}{5} \forall |z| \geq 5$,

$\underline{\textit{Wrongly Applied Liouville's Theorem}}:$

Applying Liouville's theorem as $f$ is entire and bounded so $f$ must be constant .

Also as given $f(0) = 1$, so $f = 1$ for all $z$ such that $|z| \geq 5$, but then it fails to satisfy the second inequality gven $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|} \leq \frac{1}{5}\forall |z| \geq 5$.

In this method we have not proved that $f$ is bounded over the whole complex plane ,we did so only for the region $|z| \geq 5$.Hence we cannot apply Liouvilles theorem until we prove that $f(z)$ is bounded in $|f(z)|\leq 5$

$\textbf{EDIT}$

As corrected , $|zf(z)| \leq 1 \forall |z | \geq 5$ and also $|zf(z)| \leq 1 \forall |z| \leq 5$ thus $|zf(z)|$ is bounded in the Whole of the Complex Plane.

Implying that $zf(z) = c$ (a constant function) where c is any real number.
By using the given condition $f(0) = 1$ we get $c = 0$ so $zf(z) = 0$ possible only when $f(z) = 0$, which violates thegiven condition that $f(0) = 1$.

Ths such an entire function does not exist.

Comment: You can apply Liouville's theorem only for **Bounded** entire function. How you can say that $f$ is bounded ?

Comment: "$|f(z)| \le 1/5$ for all $z$ such that $|z| \ge 5$ " does not imply that $f$ is bounded in $\Bbb C$

Comment: @S717717 By maximum modulus principle i think the bound still holds.

Comment: @ilovewt NOt getting your point. Can you please give more detail? Where I will use max-modulus ?

Comment: @S717717 The answer wrote $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{5}$ for all $|z| \geq 5$. Since $f$ is assumed to be entire and by the maximum modulus principle, $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{5}$ for all $|z| < 5$ as well. Just that he did not mention it.

Comment: I agree and you are correct @S717717

Comment: May be you are right but how can we use Maximum modulus principle to show that $|f| \leq \frac{1}{5} \forall |z| < 5$ ?@ilovewt

Comment: @ilovewt I'm also not getting your argument properly. How you use max-modulus ?

Comment: @S717717 Consider the boundary $|z| = 5$, we have found out that on this boundary, $|f| \leq \frac{1}{5}$. By the maximum modulus principle, if $f$ is an non constant and analytic function, the maximum will occur on the boundary and never inside, hence  we got us a bound for the region where $|z| < 5$.

Comment: @S717717 But it is given that $f(0) = 1$, hence a contradiction will occur in any case.

Comment: Got it..Thanks.

Comment: Nice one @ilovewt

Comment: no problem @S717717

Comment: Thanks @BAYMAX so technically you are not wrong, just need to mention  a bit more

Answer (score 5):

From your given condition , $|zf(z)|\le 1$ fort all $z$ such that $|z|\ge 5$. So $zf(z)$ is bounded in $|z| \ge 5$.

Again $zf(z)$ is analytic and as $|z| \le 5$ is compact domain so , $zf(z)$ is bounded in $|z| \le 5$. Therefore , $zf(z)$ is bounded in $\Bbb C$ and so by Liouville's theorem , $zf(z)$ is constant.

Let , $zf(z)=C.$ Now $f(0)=1$ givs $C=0$, then $f(z)=0$ , which contradicts $f(0)=1$.

So such function does not exists.

Comment: Actually how can we get this one - $zf(z)$ is analytic and $|z| \leq 5$ is compact domain so $zf(z)$ is bounded in $|z| \leq 5$ ?

Comment: Analytic implies continuous. And continuous on a compact domain implies bdd.

Comment: @S717717:is my way to solve this problem i.e,using concept of removable singularity wrong??